# Get objects from RKMappingResult

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

How would I manage to get objects of a specific type from `RKMappingResult`? 
I need to establish a relationship from the mapped data in the `RKMappingResult`s to an existing object.

I have tried:

```
[self getObjectsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BASEURL restaurant.remoteID.stringValue] parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {


        if (!mappingResult.array  || !mappingResult.array.count) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                 NSError *error = [self requestFailed];
                if (block) {
                    block(nil, error);
                }

            }) ;
        } else {
            __block BOOL done = NO;
            [[[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext] performBlockAndWait:^{

               for (Menu *menu in mappingResult.array) {
                    [restaurant addMenuObject:menu];
                }

                for (TableIds *tableId in mappingResult.array) {                  
                    [restaurant addTableIdsObject:tableId];
                     NSLog(@"%@", tableId);
                }


                [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] saveBackgroundContext];
                done = YES;

            }];
            if (done) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    if (block) {
                        block(mappingResult, nil);
                    }
                });
            }


        }



    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if (block) {
                block(nil, error);
            }

        }) ;
    }];
```

In the for loop I try to get the two type of objects which has been mapped, but for some reason it seems that it can't find the difference between `TableId` and a `Menu`. So some menus get added as a tableId an crashes the app.

What I recieve when I for example `NSLog` all the `TableIds`:

```
<Menu: 0x20e4dda0> (entity: Menu; id: 0xf19eec0 <x-coredata://9F31F549-BE4D-434C-935F-F689839989F2/Menu/p39> ; data: { ......
```

How can I get the correct objects and establish the relationships correctly?

Answer (score 3):

The success block is called on the main thread so you don't need switches or background contexts.

If you were going to use a background context, you shouldn't be directly using the returned managed objects - you would need to get each managed objects id and look it up in the other context...

The `mappingResult` can return an `array` and a `dictionary`, where the dictionary keys are the key paths of the response descriptors that created the objects. So, if you have multiple response descriptors with different key paths you should use the `dictionary` instead.

If you can't do that then you need to filter the items as you process them. Setting the class type in the fast enumeration won't do that for you (that would be black magic), you need to do it yourself:

```
for (NSManagedObject *object in mappingResult.array) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[Menu class]]) {
        [restaurant addMenuObject:(Menu *)menu];
    } else if ([object isKindOfClass:[TableIds class]]) {
        [restaurant addTableIdsObject:(TableIds *)tableId];
    }
}
```